# Longest increasing contiguous sebsequenece where beginning element is greater than ending element div 2

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have a sorted array, and I want to find efficiently the longest contiguous subsequense beginning to end so as `array[begin]>=array[end] div 2`.

The obvious is (O^(n^2) ), but is there something better?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in linear time. First lets start with the quadratic :

1. Start at the first position with index `i`
2. Put index `j` at the position of index `i+1`
3. As long as the end of the array is not reached and the element `a[j]/2 <= a[i]`, increment j
4. record the "score" of index `i`.
5. increment index i and go back to step 2.
6. When all indexes are covered, take the index with max score.

The catch is to realize that if you fail on step 3 for a pair `(i, j)`, then it means :

```
for every i < k < j, a[k] <= a[i]/2
a[j] > a[i]/2
```

Thus, at step 5, going to any `k` smaller than `j` will lead to a smaller score, because `a[j] > a[i]/2 > a[k]/2`. Thus the next index to start with is `j`.

By now we are visiting an index at most once when computing any score. Which reduces this step from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)`. Then taking the index with maximum score is obviously `O(n)`.

Comment: at step 3, do you mean a[j] / 2 <=a[i]?